# What is the difference between Shiksha and Pratishakhya granth?

Tags: vedas, samhita

Are Pratishkhya granth and Shiksha the same?

I want to know the rules of pronouncing letters in samhita of Shukla Yajurveda, Madhyandini shakha. Should I look for a Shikha granth or Pratishakya?